# make column default value during migration not working in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, schema

I am trying to give 'is_img' column to default value '0' during migration. When I am trying like - `$table->integer('is_img')->defalut(0)->change();` It's removing existing column during migration. When trying without change() method, then it's giving null value during migration. What should I do to keep the default value for the column during migration? Here is Schema bellow -

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('user_name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('login_type');
        $table->integer('is_img')->defalut(0)->change();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Try: `$table->integer('is_img')->dafault(0)->change();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
$table->integer('is_img')->defalut(0)->change();
```

Should be `default(0)` not `defalut(0)`.